# In the Soviet Union, why was the Cheka renamed so many times?

Tags: soviet-union, police, kgb

The Cheka was the secret police of the USSR. Wikipedia maintains [a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_Soviet_secret_police_agencies) of the Cheka and its subsequent renamings:

- 1917: Cheka
- 1922: GPU
- 1923: OGPU
- 1934: NKVD
- 1941: NKGB
- 1941: NKVD (again)
- 1943: NKGB (again)
- 1946: MGB
- 1954: KGB

It stops at KGB in 1954. This is roughly when Khrushchev came to power. The renamings start in 1922. Though Lenin had not died yet, 1922 - 1954 is roughly the era of Stalin. So I wonder, does this have anything to do with Stalin's rise to power or control via the Chekists? If so, how? How could renaming accomplish this or serve some other purpose? Were there really significant re-organizations each time it was renamed?

Comment: Don't forget the [FSB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Security_Service)!

Comment: @axsvl77 the FSB is not an organ of the USSR.

Comment: Meant it as a [Tongue in Cheek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-in-cheek)

Comment: But the table clearly shows that the Cheka was only renamed once! ;-)

Comment: I'd always thought it was, consciously or otherwise, a rebranding exercise - that when the organisation was at risk of becoming particularly notorious, it renamed itself.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Technically correct, the best kind of correct.

Comment: Because if people knew what they were called then how secret could they be?? >D No seriously I have no idea, I'm just fooling around.

Comment: @axsvl77 And don't forget the Okhrana of Imperial Russia, but like others said, only USSR. I was actually afraid the question might be considered too broad as it is, since 1917-1954 covers a lot of stuff.

Comment: I'm surprised that there's a factually-based answer to this. I would have merely speculated that a loathsome organisation may constantly change its name to marginally decrease the taint associated its name.

Comment: They tried to find out, but the prisoner died without revealing the reason. :-)

Comment: Cheka is actually an acronym ChK.

Comment: The secret police have always been called the KGB.  Also, we have always been at war with Eastasia.

Comment: @axsvl77 You might as well go all the way back to the the [Oprichnina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oprichnina).

Comment: as everyone is telling jokes: **the soviet version of 'who watches the watchmen?' is 'who purges the purgers?'** if you did not get the joke, it means that the next acronym are the ones who purged the last one. On a more serious note, really the different secret services watched each other.

Comment: It didn't really stop at KGB: modern Russia, which after two decades or relative transparency is returning to the old way of thinking and old ambitions, renamed KGB into FSB. The same men that used to be KGB are now FSB, and the organization's role is basically the same.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The secret police was key to the Soviet government (so-called Chekism), so its structure changed frequently in response to state political needs.

- CheKa: The "Emergency Commission" was formed in 1917, at the start of the Civil War, and was structured as appropriate for such a time - most notably, it was empowered to act extrajudicially. After the Civil War ended, The  [Ninth All-Russian Soviet Congress](http://elib.shpl.ru/ru/nodes/10874-xi-vserossiyskiy-s-ezd-sovetov-19-29-yanvarya-1924-g-stenograficheskiy-otchet-m-1924#page/1/mode/grid/zoom/1) dissolved the CheKa and created the GPU, an organization more appropriate for a real country that was, in theory, more restrained by laws and rules.
- GPU/OGPU: The "O" stands for Joint, and was added after the various Soviet republics joined together to form the USSR in 1922, and the Russian agency had to [become a Union one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_Political_Directorate#Disestablishment). While the original GPU reported to the NKVD of the Russian Republic, the OGPU reported to the SovNarKom (the executive government branch of the USSR).
- NKVD: The NKVD of the Russian Republic was [transformed into an All-Union organization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NKVD#History_and_structure), and so they got their secret police back. This change also coincides with the beginning of the Great Purge, so it was likely that Stalin found it advantageous to arrange the state apparatus this way.
- NKGB: The NKVD soon became a target of the purges themselves. The [secret police component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/People%27s_Commissariat_for_State_Security#Separate_administration) was pulled out to make this more effective, then rolled back in during the war as an intelligence/counterintelligence arm, then taken out again to police occupied Eastern Europe.
- MGB: The ["people's komissariat" was changed to the "ministry"](http://eao.memo27reg.org/o-preobrazovanii-soveta-narodnyh-komissarov-sssr-v-sovet-ministrov-sssr-i-sovetov-narodnyh-komissarov-souznyh-i-avtonomnyh-respublik-v-sovety-ministrov-souznyh-i-avtonomnyh-respublik); this was a change that affected all agencies as the USSR was rebuilding and reorganizing after the war. Nothing changed except the agency name.
- KGB: Stalin died in 1953, and the de-Stalinization process touched all parts of the government, [including the MGB](http://shieldandsword.mozohin.ru/nkgb4353/index.htm). The KGB resulted from a merger of the MGB and the MVD (the non-secret police); however, the MVD broke off again in 1954.

Note that the renaming and restructuring was fairly transparent to the population, and there was no "rebranding" effort - security officers were informally called "Chekists" up until the dissolution of the USSR.

Comment: Almost perfect answer. You got just one thing wrong: latter-day MVD and KGB were independent (and to an extent, rival) bodies.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg Ah, sorry - missed that the MVD broke off again in 1954. The history of the secret police is such a whirlwind.

Comment: I'd feel better about my upvote with a reference or two added as well.

Comment: I am speculating:  name changes were related to purges.  The GPU liquidated the Cheka, the NKVD liquidated the GPU, etc.

Comment: Are you listing these bullet points from memory? If so, what books or articles give these explanations?

Comment: Added sources - please note that primary sources are not just in Russian, but in dense bureaucratic Russian.

Comment: I think it is important to note that Stalin died in March 1953, and immediately [Lavrentiy Beria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lavrentiy_Beria) - earlier the People's Commissars of NKVD and one of the major contenders for the power - was appointed the chief of the newly merged MVD (Ministry of Internal Affairs) = old MVD (police) + NKVD (secret police), but he quickly lost this struggle and was executed late in 1953 (as well as a few other secret police leaders). And then early in 1954 MVD was split back into independent MVD (police) and KGB (secret police).

Comment: This answer has additional explanation, but note that this is also discussed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chronology_of_Soviet_secret_police_agencies

Comment: @FelixGoldberg: It is fundamental to the nature of intelligence organizations (as well as other military orgs) that even if working for the same country they will tend to be rivals, sometimes bitterly so. Conflicts in the USA between local police and FBI were common.

Answer (score 1):

An "umbrella" organization such as the [Cheka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheka) was literally made up of hundreds of sub organizations with different purposes.

These suborganizations were recombined at various times under different chiefs to constitute new organizations with slightly different (mostly) internal mandates, and new umbrella organizations, with new names were created most of these times. For instance, the secret and non-secret police merged and de-merged from time to time.

The only thing that was constant was the ever-presence of the "organs." The forms often changed but the substance, seldom.